# How can i add "Add External Jar" to my project in android

Tags: android

I want to add banner to my project. I have done some work in this regard, but i have problem in adding "Add External jar".

[Right click on my Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External jar].

Now my problem is, as I click "Add External jar" a new widow(browsing) opens and asking for to open jar file, but I have studied "Android Developer documents" for adding banner in project, there was nothing mentioned about the to open jar file. Now what I have to do, to add "Add External jar" and I could continue my project further.

Yours help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank`s in advance.

Comment: create a libs folder in your project and put jar file into that project. After that right click on that jar file and select add to build path option.

Comment: Please guide me that how can I create libs folder in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How can i add “Add External Jar” to my project in android

For, this i always follow below steps -

1. Just create a libs folder on my project ->And, copy the `.jar` file to there.
2. In your workspace select your project and right click -> on Properties, just go to `Java Build Path`
3. Click the `Add External jars` it'll open the window dialog box -> root your workspace -> And, select your project -> go to `libs` folder -> choose the `.jar file` -> Click ok.

Hope these steps helps you.

Comment: Dear i want to "Add External Jar" let me know about

Comment: Actually i want to add "Google AdMob Ads JAR"

Comment: @FarmanKhan Okay. Did you copy the `Google AdMob Ads JAR` file into your project's `libs` folder?

Comment: No I haven't copied the Google AdMob Ads JAR file into my project's libs folder; what is the procedure? please guide me.

Comment: [Try to watch this video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?gl=IN&hl=en&client=mv-google&v=eY_uqi_qIz0)

Comment: Ya Dear! I am following the steps but,where is the "Google AdMob Ads JAR" in my SDK to copy into my libs folder.

Comment: [You've to download that from web](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a jar file that you downloaded that contains he libraries you need. You'll need to select that jarfile for the step that you are doing currently.

It is a good idea to keep that file within your project folder as well. Many people like to keep all of their libraries inside of a folder called libs within their project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "banner" is, but if it's an Android Project it cannot be added as a JAR. Projects that have resources are not able to be fully externally liked libs.

If indeed this is Android Project you will need to import the existing project into your Eclipse workspace here the steps http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called "libs" in your project.

Go to that folder using Windows Explorer and copy the .jar file there.

Refresh your project in eclipse and right click on the jar file and select "Add to Build Path" option.