# How can i create libs folder in my project Android

Tags: android

How can I create Libs folder in my android project. I want to "Add External Jar".

Comment: as you create other folder .... :) just in parallel to src folder of your project........and refresh project in eclipse and it should be "libs"

Comment: Did you follow the steps on my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11084158/940096)

Comment: dude if my answer is helpful to u then u can vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Right click on Yout project  -> Click on New -> goto Folder -> Give Folder name
```

**To Add .jars in libs**

```
Right click on res folder -> Goto Build path -> click on Add External jar
or
Right click on res folder -> Goto Build path -> Configure build path -> From Left side menu Select "Java Build path" ->There will be 4 tabs Click on Libraries -> Click on Add Externals JARs..
```

Answer (score 5):

`Your Project->Right Click->New->Folder->give name libs->Finish`.add lib file in libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

As normal as you create in normal java project.

Rignt CLick on your project-->> new -->> folder ->> give the name.

After that add jar file into this folder then right click on your project  -->> Build Path -->>Add external Achives