# Why com.google.ad is missing?

Tags: android, import

I'm adding ad to my test app according to:

[Google Developer: Mobile Ads SDK - Android Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals)

and I am stuck at line:

```
import com.google.ads.*;
```

Eclipse only shows available:

```
com.google.maps
```

why, please help.

I downloaded this:

[Google Mobile Ad SDK For Android (zip)](http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googleadmobadssdkandroid.zip)

from here:

[Google Developer: Mobile ADs SDK Download](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download)

Comment: Have you included jar in build path???

Comment: @iNan
like this?

http://i.imgur.com/1SHoS.png

http://i.imgur.com/L0XBU.png

Comment: Try to import that `.jar` file only. Don't try to import the `.zip` file as directly

Comment: @SpK

works perfect, thx :)
i have to unpack downloaded file and use *.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of directly import that `.zip` file to your project. So try to do like this -

Extract the `.zip` file and import that `.jar` file which is extracted from that `.zip` file as per [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084158/940096)

Hope this helps you.